# Is it possible to inject extra annotations to classes before annotation processing?

Tags: java, maven, annotations, preprocessor, code-injection

Imagine the following:

```
@MyAnnotation
public class A { ... };

@MyOtherAnnotation
public class B { ... };
```

If a class is annotated with `@MyAnnotation`, an extra `@MyExtraAnnotation` should be added before annotation processing. So, after that step, we should have:

```
@MyExtraAnnotation
@MyAnnotation
public class A { ... };

@MyOtherAnnotation
public class B { ... };
```

Is this possible? If yes how? Thanks.

Comment: That depends on when you want to process the annotations. If you're processing them at load time or runtime you could definitely add some at compile time - what's the  If all happens at compile time, it should be possible as well but you might have to keep an eye on the order of operations - I'm not sure on this however.

Comment: I need to add them at compile time, before annotation propcessing, which happens at compile time too.

Comment: what's maven's relevance to the question?

Comment: If you have a solution without Maven, I am interested too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the `process-sources` phase of the [lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference), or possibly the `annotationProcessors` configuration of the [maven compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#annotationProcessors).

I've not found a plugin that "adds annotations", but is certainly should be possible to create one to do just that.

Comment: Well, I have taken a look at annotation processors, but I don't really see how I could do it. I could regenerate the class code into a new class and add an annotation, but that is heavy. If I could only modify existing code and add this annotation, that would be great.

Comment: The process-sources is probably easier, if you feel comfortable processing text. There's another SO question that relates [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187550/preprocessing-source-code-as-a-part-of-a-maven-build]. If you can call an external process, say perl, and do a substitution, it'd be easy (if a bit messy). s/@MyAnnotation/@MyExtraAnnotation\n@MyAnnotation/g