# Use Maven to pre-process source code that is going to be built with Maven

Tags: java, maven, build, preprocessor

I have the following example source code:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
  void method1();

  @Support
  void method2();

  @Support(ENVIRONMENT_A)
  void method3();

  @Support({ ENVIRONMENT_A, ENVIRONMENT_B })
  void method4();
}
```

The above API can be used in various environments, among which `A` and `B` (for instance, A=Oracle, B=MySQL). In order to communicate which method is supported in which environment, I have added `@Support` annotations with the following semantics:

- No `@Support` annotation means that the corresponding method does not depend on environments
- An "empty" `@Support` annotation means that the corresponding method is supported in all environments
- A parameterised `@Support` annotation means that the corresponding method is only supported in the environments supplied as annotation arguments.

To improve this communication with API clients, I would like to write a Maven plugin that can be used for API pre-processing. That plugin would take a list of environments as parameter in order to deprecate all methods that will not be supported in ALL the supplied environments.

Some examples:

- I run the plugin with `ENVIRONMENT_A`: No effect on the interface. All methods are supported in `ENVIRONMENT_A`
- I run the plugin with `ENVIRONMENT_B`: The resulting interface should look like this

  ```
  public interface SomeInterface {
    void method1();

    @Support
    void method2();

    /* @deprecated - Not supported in ENVIRONMENT_B */
    @Support(ENVIRONMENT_A)
    @Deprecated
    void method3();

    @Support({ ENVIRONMENT_A, ENVIRONMENT_B })
    void method4();
  }
  ```
- I run the plugin with both `ENVIRONMENT_A` and `ENVIRONMENT_B`:

  ```
  public interface SomeInterface {
    void method1();

    @Support
    void method2();

    /* @deprecated - Not supported in both ENVIRONMENT_A *AND* ENVIRONMENT_B */
    @Support(ENVIRONMENT_A)
    @Deprecated
    void method3();

    @Support({ ENVIRONMENT_A, ENVIRONMENT_B })
    void method4();
  }
  ```

So in other words, that plugin should transform all sources in src/main/java according to the above rules, before compiling the sources in src/main/java. The original sources should remain untouched in order for this to be reproducible any time. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preprocessing source code as a part of a maven build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187550/preprocessing-source-code-as-a-part-of-a-maven-build)

Comment: ... OK, why don't I just google it ... ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187550/preprocessing-source-code-as-a-part-of-a-maven-build

Answer (score 0):

[Preprocessing source code as a part of a maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187550/preprocessing-source-code-as-a-part-of-a-maven-build) seems like an answer but it really isn't because it ignores a lot of details:

1. Maven can call external tools during the build but you still need a tool to process your sources.
2. How do you plan to keep the Maven Java compiler away from the files in `src/*/java`? If you don't get it right, it will try to compile both the original source and the transformed ones.
3. How do you plan to edit the original sources? If you move the original sources to a different folder, tools like m2e will prevent you from editing them in, say, Eclipse because they read your POM to determine the paths.
4. Developers looking at the code will be pretty confused because they are used to Maven and Maven says: "The sources in src/*/java will be compiled and end up in the artifact". So you are violating convention.